# Is there a way to lock record in Access database

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I need to find a way to get unique "Verification" from MS Access database in multi-users environment. Here's my table example:

[image]

Field Verification is already prefilled and will be never changed, mID, and getDate are added/deleted by user (using VBA script).
The rule for VBA script is:
1. Find first free row of mID,
2. Fill it with current user Name, and current Date,
3. Return corresponding Verification field

Seems easy to do, here's code I've developed:

```
Function access() As String

    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Records As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim record As ADODB.record

    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Set Records = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set record = New record

    con.ConnectionString = sDBPath
    con.Open

    With Records
        .ActiveConnection = con
        .Source = "tblVerificationNr"
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
        .Open

    Do Until .EOF
        If IsNull(.Fields("mID")) Then
            access = .Fields(1)
            .Fields("mID") = "asdf"
            .Fields("getDate") = Now
            .Update
            Exit Do
        End If
        .MoveNext
    Loop

    End With

End Function
```

Code works well for 1 user, but when multiple users starts querying it at (almost) same time, then they receive the same Verification number.
(If User2 sends request 0,1 sec later than User1, then they'll find the same row - Verification = 3006. It will result that first User1 will put his mID and getDate AND will receive Verification = 3006, but 0.1 sec later User2 will overwrite this data and receive the same verification number).

What would be a work-around for this one? How to ensure Verification uniqueness? Is it possible to "lock" found record by user1, so user2 would not be able to find this one?

Tried it with SQL statements as well:

```
sSelectSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 tblVerificationNr.VerificationNumber, tblVerificationNr.Mid, tblVerificationNr.getDate FROM tblVerificationNr WHERE (((tblVerificationNr.[mID]) = '" & UserName() & "')) ORDER BY tblVerificationNr.getDate DESC, tblVerificationNr.ID"
sUpdateSQL = "UPDATE (SELECT TOP 1 tblVerificationNr.VerificationNumber, tblVerificationNr.Mid, tblVerificationNr.getDate FROM tblVerificationNr WHERE (((IsNull([tblVerificationNr].[mID]))<>False)) ORDER BY tblVerificationNr.VerificationNumber)  AS a SET a.mID = '" & UserName() & "', getDate = '" & Now() & "'"
```

and the same issue here.

Comment: I think you'd be better tackling this in SQL using update/insert and where clauses? Something along these lines `update tblVerificationNr
set mid='Nathan'
(select min(id) where mid is null and getdate is null)`  The new ID would be `(select min(id) where mid is null and getdate is null)`

Comment: @HansUp version should work without the `[ ]` in the criteria argument. In VBA, change those quote marks to apostrophes. Even with SQL there is still very, very slim chance users could get same record. I use this approach and never had an issue. However, code does not deal with possibility there are no 'empty' records.

Comment: Thought as much but the `[ ]` aren't really needed because field names do not have spaces nor special characters but they won't hurt.

Comment: Any reason for Verification already prefilled? If you use`Insert`queries with a unique index it would be easier to prevent users conflicting. So if possible create a new row with an insert each time. If users conflict only the first can insert data, the next ones will receive an error and can try the next Verification number. If prefilled Verification is mandatory, use a second table and insert Verification, Username and Date to that table.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea and would help with new records, but anyway I still need to fill empty records when user deletes some value (See ID=6 in my screenshot)

Comment: @ComputerVersteher - actually you inspired me to find a solution. I've created a support table with field: "UniqueID" - this one is indexed (no duplicates). I'm using transaction to get value from "Verification", and then insert new row (with this value) to support table "UniqueID" field. If erorr occures, then I Rollback whole Transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised users are getting same number. Try `adLockPessimistic` and instead of pulling entire table, pull just 1 record.

`.Source = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tblVerificationNr WHERE mID IS NULL ORDER BY ID;"`

Sort by VerificationNumber if you prefer, but probably make sure sort field is indexed in table.

Then don't loop, just set values of fields:

```
If Not .EOF Then
    .Fields("mID") = "asdf"
    .Fields("getDate") = Now
    .Update
    access = .Fields(1)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but same issue here - works well for 1 user, but when 2 users send requrest within 1 second they receive the same results. Is it possible this is some 
Aceess Option - I've tried different "Deafult open mode" and "Default record locking" options and still the same. Is is possible that this is some "Share Drive" configuration? (where DB is stored).

Comment: @MichałPlich: Check`.LockType`after`.Open`. `CursorLocation`needs to be`adUseServer`or [LockType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/locktype-property-ado?view=sql-server-2017) changes.